# I made a bot blacklist but the bot gets stuck in a loop when anyone uses anything

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a blacklist for the bot, it "works", it blocks the blacklisted user from using the bot but ended up causing a loop and the blacklisted message to get spammed, both when a blacklisted user uses it and when someone that isnt on the blacklist uses it

heres the code

```js
client.on('message', async message => {

    let blacklist = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#e31212")
  .setDescription(
    "ERROR: You are not allowed to use this bot | Reason: BLACKLISTED"
  );
var blacklistids = ["402639792552017920", "711957885722296360"];
if (blacklistids.includes(message.author.id)) {
    message.channel.send(blacklist).then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
      })
}
// Rest of the code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct - but by how you've described it, it would seem to me your code is wrapped in a loop somewhere else. Have you tried creating another `client.on()` with different conditions to see if those messages also get looped/spammed?.

This is something that can easily occur, especially if you are a beginner.

EDIT: you are however missing `});` at the end of your `client.on()` declaration.

Comment: About the client.on() yes i actually tried that but it still havent worked

And no, i actually am not missing and it is in fact in the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your IDs in the array might be the bot's ID... if this is the case, you might also want to have a `if(message.author.bot) return` after the `client.on(...`